# Make FAT32 disks starts with boot

Tags: boot, mount, fat32

i'm using ubuntu 14.10 utopic beta 2 (waiting for the officiel release)
i've two partitions (FAT32) where i save my documents..
i would like to make those two partitions starts with boot.more clearly, to mount them when the system start...
i hope my question was clear.
Thanks !

Comment: Mounting any partition at boot regardless of supported filesystem is configured in fstab. Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/303497/adding-an-entry-to-fstab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been aswered a few times possibly, anyway something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/336996/182214) might help.